# How does k work in Matrix Multiplication in C?

Tags: c, math, matrix, matrix-multiplication

How does **k** works in the code below?

```
# include <stdio.h>
# define R 2
# define C 2

int main(void)
{
    int a[R][C], b[R][C], mul[R][C], i, j, k;
        for (i = 0; i < R; ++i)
            for (j = 0; j < C; ++j)
            {
                scanf_s("%d", &a[i][j]);
            }

        for (i = 0; i < R; ++i)
            for (j = 0; j < C; ++j)
            {
                scanf_s("%d", &b[i][j]);
            }

        for (i = 0; i < R; ++i)
            for (j = 0; j < C; ++j)
            {
                mul[i][j] = 0;
                for (k = 0; k < C; ++k)
                {
                    mul[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
                }
                printf("%d", mul[i][j]);
                if (j == 0)
                {
                    printf(" ");
                }

                else if (i == 0 && j == 1)
                {
                    printf("\n");
                }
            }
    return 0;
}
```

For matrix addition, I know that in math **sum[0][0] = a[0][0] + b[0][0]** and in code also be like this.

For matrix multiplication, it is **mul[0][0] = a[0][0] x b[0][0] + a[0][0] x b[1][0]** in math.

However in code, [ ] is not only come from i and j but also k.

`scanf_s("%d", &a[i][j]);` and `scanf_s("%d", &b[i][j]);` has shown that %d are saved in memory a[i][j] and b[i][j].

So, what did **k** be read in `mul[i][j] = a[i][k] * b[k][j];` ?

Comment: Where did you find the code from? What documentation were available from that place? What do you know about the operations being done on the matrices? And what is your original exercise/assignment?

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them.

Comment: The paragraph that starts "For matrix multiplication" and ends with "in math" is wrong. As soon as you understand how matrix multiplication actually works in math, you'll understand the need for `k`.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your misunderstanding starts here:

> For matrix multiplication, it is `mul[0][0] = a[0][0] x b[0][0] + a[0][0] x b[1][0]` in math.

That's **not** how matrix multiplication works.

If you look at this code for `i == 0` and `j == 0` and `C == 2`

```
            mul[i][j] = 0;
            for (k = 0; k < C; ++k)
            {
                mul[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
            }
```

it becomes

```
            mul[0][0] = 0;
            for (k = 0; k < 2; ++k)
            {
                mul[0][0] += a[0][k] * b[k][0];
            }
```

Since `k` will take the values `0` and `1` it results in

```
mul[0][0] = a[0][0] * b[0][0] + a[0][1] * b[1][0];
                 ^      ^            ^      ^
                   k = 0              k = 1
```

As you can see this is different from what you expected. And it's the correct way to do it for multiplication in case of 2X2 matrix.

Had it been 3X3 matrix, it would be:

```
mul[0][0] = a[0][0] * b[0][0] + a[0][1] * b[1][0] + a[0][2] * b[2][0];
                 ^      ^            ^      ^            ^      ^
                   k = 0              k = 1                k = 2
```

So the the loop using `k` as index, takes care of multiplying a row from `a` with a column of `b`.